# Does pouchdb leave deleted tombstones like couchdb does?

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I have a hybrid app that generates a lot of tombstones on couchdb.  About 100,000 a month on the server.  Each user should be getting about 4 a day.
Does Pouchdb maintain tombstones? Or do they get compacted or purged?  Or is there a command to do that? Or do I have to drop the database and recreate periodically?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pouchdb does [keep a tombstone](https://pouchdb.com/guides/updating-deleting.html#deleting-documents) when deleting a document.

Purge is not available yet for PouchDB so the only way to completely deletes documents is by deleting the local database.